# matlab2tikz width of figure incorrect

Tags: alignment, matlab2tikz

Using `matlab2tikz` I experience a strange behavior. My idea was, following https://tomlankhorst.nl/matlab-to-latex-with-matlab2tikz/, to create a figure in Matlab (R2019) and then use it in Latex within the IEEE two-column preset.

I created two figures to demonstrate the problem:

[image]

1. As you can see, the upper image is the same as the lower, however, a ylabel is added, which increases the width of the image.
2. The second image may has columnwidth exactly, but is not aligned correctly.

So my question is, how can I ensure the image exactly having the width of the text of a column, independent of having a ylabel or not? Can anybody help?

My code:

```matlab
figure()
plot(sin(0:.01:pi));
matlab2tikz('../../Ausarbeitung/Images/test2.tex', 'width', '\figW');
figure()
plot(sin(0:.01:pi));
ylabel('label');
matlab2tikz('../../Ausarbeitung/Images/test.tex', 'width', '\figW');
```

```
\begin{figure}
\setlength\figW{1.0\columnwidth}
\centering
\input{Images/test.tex}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setlength\figW{1.0\columnwidth}
\centering
\input{Images/test2.tex}
\end{figure}
```

Plus the following in the tex header 
`\newlength\figW`

Comment: Is there a `scale only axis` in `test.tex`?

Comment: This might be a bit tricky due to how `pgfplots` sets the size of axes. When one sets `width=5cm`, the width of the axis box itself gets set to 5cm - 45pt, where the 45pt is a hardcoded length to make room for labels. Because labels usually won't be exactly 45pt wide, the total width will usually not be exactly 5cm. If one does ``width=5cm,scale only axis`, the width of the axis 5cm, so the total width becomes 5cm + <the width taken up by the labels>. I'm guessing `matlab2tikz` adds `scale only axis`.

Comment: You could put the `\input` in a `\resizebox`, but that has the problem of resizing the font.

Comment: Yes, matlab2tikz adds the line `scale only axis`, but how does this help, I cannot follow, sorry. Removing the line changes the aspect ratio.
`\resizebox` is a good idea, but due o the font resizing no option for me.
Hence, the only option is to set a rough value that fits more or less, an exact solution is not possible, right?

Comment: Sorry, the `scale only axis` stuff was more of an explanation of what happens. You can turn it off with `'extraAxisOptions', 'scale only axis=false'` added to the `matlab2tikz` call (if I got the Matlab syntax right), but that still won't make it exactly `\columnwidth`, for the reasons explained above.